# Can Ignite 3's thin client connect to an Ignite 2 cluster to execute SQL?

Tags: ignite

I'm currently working with Apache Ignite and have a setup where I'm using Ignite 2's cluster. I recently came across Ignite 3 and its thin client capabilities. I was wondering if it's possible for the Ignite 3 thin client to connect to an Ignite 2 cluster and execute SQL queries against it?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite 3.x client won't be compatible with Ignite 2.x, there are too many differences in the protocol and APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can't. Currenetly the TcpClientChannel in ignite 3.x only support ProtocolVersion.V3_0_0.I'm not entirely sure I'm right